# Log to tensorboard an internal loss function in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have been implementing my first Variational Autoencoder for a custom application I am working in. Everything runs smoothly but **I am not able to log the KL term to Tensorboard** at each batch forward pass. I want this in order to gain inside on the model and to study the effect of KL annealing techniques.

I've defined my model from the examples on the TF documentation webpage, **meaning that the KL term is added to the current batch loss by the `Model.add_loss()` function**:

```
class VariationalAutoEncoder(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self,
             original_dim=18,
             intermediate_dim=64,
             latent_dim=2,
             name='Autoencoder',
             **kwargs):
    super(VariationalAutoEncoder, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.original_dim = original_dim
    self.encoder = Encoder(latent_dim=latent_dim,
                           intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim)
    self.decoder = Decoder(original_dim=original_dim,
                           intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim)
    self.kl_loss_weight = 0

def call(self, inputs):
    # Forward pass of the Encoder
    z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(inputs)
    # Forward pass of the Decoder taken the re-parameterized z latent variable
    reconstructed = self.decoder(z)

    # Add KL divergence regularization loss for this forward pass
    # THIS IS THE VALUE I WANT TO LOG TO TENSORBOARD
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var) + 1)

    # HERE !!!! I ADD THE KL TERM weighted by an internal variable.
    self.add_loss(self.kl_loss_weight * kl_loss)
    return reconstructed
```

I define, compile and train my model with the built-in functions (I am not defining a custom training loop):

```
vae = VariationalAutoEncoder(original_dim=18, intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim, latent_dim=latent_dim)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)

vae.compile(optimizer,
            loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
            metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(name="reconstruction_MAE")])
```

With this setup, I am able to get in Tensorboard logs of the combined loss function (Reconstruction + KL) and also only reconstruction (by use of the MAE metric). **Nevertheless, I cannot seem to find a way to also log the KL term, since its value is computed inside the graph**.

I have tried to use a multi-output configuration but it requires assigning constant `loss_weights`, which I need to avoid since I want to use KL annealing.

**I would like to avoid to write a custom training loop so I am able to do this, but I have tried several ideas so far and now I believe it might be the only way. Am I wrong? Is there a way to log this internal loss value to Tensorboard?**

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [tf.summary.scalar](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras#logging_custom_scalars):

```
class VariationalAutoEncoder(tf.keras.Model):
    <...>
    def call(self, inputs):
        <...>
        kl_loss = - 0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var) + 1)
        tf.summary.scalar('KL loss', kl_loss)
        self.add_loss(self.kl_loss_weight * kl_loss)
        return reconstructed

logdir = "logs/scalars/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir + "/metrics")
file_writer.set_as_default()
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
vae = VariationalAutoEncoder(original_dim=18, intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim, latent_dim=latent_dim)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)

vae.compile(optimizer,
            loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
            metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(name="reconstruction_MAE"),
            callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
```